# How find integral of circle or sphere with another circle(sphere) inside?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

I am stuck with one problem regarding calculating integral of one circle inside another, when circle, whenis inside located assymetrically (see Figure). What I want is two find integral of filled with blue part. (Not just area I need integral, because finally my integrand will some function wich depends on r sth like:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi \int_{r1}^{r2(\phi)} f(r) rdr$.

What I trying to do now, is just to check it firstly without $f(r)$ and compare results with area formula.
And what I get is this dependence of R2:

$r_2(\phi) = x_0 \pm \sqrt{(x_0\sin\phi)^2 - (x_0)^2 - R_2^2}$

and even without any function $f(r)$ integral is becoming very complicated.
I would like to know if you may be someone has an idea may be to change integral by places or something else

Thanks in advance,
Best

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbFGj.png)

Comment: The outer circle has the parametric/Cartesian/polar equations$$\begin{cases}x=R_2\cos\phi-x_0\\y=R_2\sin\phi\end{cases}\implies(x+x_0)^2+y^2={R_2}^2\implies r_2(\phi)=\sqrt{{R_2}^2-2x_0R_2\cos\phi+{x_0}^2}$$